# CSS - 'Common Classes' Bad practise or not?

Tags: css

I used to add what I call 'common classes' to my CSS such as:-

```
.text-color{color:#2da8d9;}
.text-white{color:#fff;}
.text-lgrey{color:#919D9D !important;}
.text-dgrey{color:#879798 !important;}
.text-dkgrey{color:#656d6e !important;}
.text-dblue{color:#15355C;}
.text-lblue{color:#1466B1;}
.nopadding{padding: 0 !important; margin: 0 !important;}
.margin0{margin:0px !important;}
.margint5{margin-top:5px !important;}
.margint10{margin-top:10px !important;}
.margint20{margin-top:20px !important;}
.margint30{margin-top:30px !important;}
.margint40{margin-top:40px !important;}
.margint50{margin-top:50px !important;}
.margint60{margin-top:60px !important;}
.margint70{margin-top:70px !important;}
.margint80{margin-top:80px !important;}
.margint90{margin-top:90px !important;}
.margint100{margin-top:100px !important;}
.margint120{margin-top:120px !important;}
.marginb10{margin-bottom:10px !important;}
.marginb20{margin-bottom:20px !important;}
.marginb30{margin-bottom:30px !important;} 
.marginb40{margin-bottom:40px !important;}
.marginb60{margin-bottom:60px !important;}
.marginb80{margin-bottom:80px !important;}
.marginb90{margin-bottom:90px !important;}
.marginb100{margin-bottom:100px !important;}
.marginb120{margin-bottom:120px !important;}
.pleftnone{padding-left:0 !important;}
.padrl20{padding:0 20px;}
.padrl50{padding:0 50px;}
.marginl20{margin-left:20px;}
.padt20{padding-top:20px;}
.padt40{padding-top:40px;}
.padt80{padding-top:80px;}
.padt60{padding-top:60px;}
.padb30{padding-bottom:30px;}
.padb40{padding-bottom:40px;}
.padb60{padding-bottom:60px;}
.padb80{padding-bottom:80px;}
.padb100{padding-bottom:100px;}
.pad5{padding:5px;}
.pad10{padding:10px;}
.pad20{padding:20px;}
.pad30{padding:30px;}
.text-center{text-align:center}
.text-right{text-align:right}
.text-left{text-align:left}
.relative-position{position:relative !important}
```

And then just add the classes when I need to use them until someone told me it's very bad practise to do this?

I find I have do add `position: relative;` on quite a lot of elements when using absolute positioning on child elements etc and for me it just seems easy to add a class rather than adding it in the CSS each time. I can understand it adds to the HTML size as your adding more classes but it's less CSS because your not adding the same styles to every class?

Just want some clarification on best practises, apologies in advance if this isn't the place to talk about this.

Comment: This question is either too broad, **opinion based** or requires discussion and so is off-topic for Stack Overflow. If you have a specific, answerable, programming issue, please provide full details.

Comment: Or move it to Code Review.

Comment: I think it's fine for structuring but I think it's really bad for styling (colors / font-style/weight...) because styling is often at another level of abstraction than structuring which is pretty high, for example you might want "important" text to be of X color, yet this color could be shared by tons of elements and that'll be really hard if you need to change everywhere since you CANNOT change a utility class once it's been used.

Comment: I think using common classes is not a bad practise.But using common class for each css style property(what you did) is a bad practise

Comment: I guess it's a preference thing - I use common classes for things like colours, shared backgrounds and sprites (so I can change them in one place) but not for things like margin and padding - I would have thought the bloat in your html would be larger than the bloat of css if you are adding 4 classes to each element for padding.

Comment: @Pete It's bad idea to use common classes for color. For example, you have button and some label with class `color-active`. What if you need to change color of all buttons not labels? You had to change html to style elements. But you should change only css to change button color.

Comment: @3rdthemagical Yep, I only use colour classes for content. Buttons have their own classes so all buttons are styled the same so if I need to change the look of a type of button, I only change it in one place - it's just using classes correctly - grouping items of the same look

Comment: @Pete Add color styles to body, p, h1, h2 and other elements to style content. It's more correct. 

For example, If you have some error message, use class `error` instead `color-some`. Using `error` you can add some other custom styles to element like margins, paddings, font-size.

Comment: @3rdthemagical As I said in my previous comment - it's all preference - you have your way, I have mine.  For example, if you are styling  p, h1, h2 etc like that, you are using a catch all selector and I would say that is bad practise - I would always add styles to a class or id

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Bad. Imagine element with class `text-white margint5 marginb10 padrl20 padb40 text-center relative-position`. It's ugly.
What if you need margin 32px? Will you add new class margint32? Will you add classes for all css properties? border-radius, font-size, font-weight and so on.

Read about **[BEM](https://en.bem.info/)**.

Comment: To be fair I would probably only ever use one of the classes at a time but I can understand what you mean. If I needed margin: 32px it's more specific so I would have added that to the ID or Class of the element

Comment: Imagine you have tons of buttons with class text-white. And now ALL buttons must have another color. What will you do? You had to search for all buttons in project and rewrite class.

Comment: @3rdthemagical - if you called that class `colour-one` instead of `text-white`, you could then just change that style in one place, rather than doing a find and replace on all things that had `color:#ffffff;`

Comment: @Pete read my comment under question.

Answer (score 0):

No if site is mobile friendly in responsive web designing it is not good to use common classes.
Example : Suppose you are using margin10 class on mobile device you want to change that value to 20 and if you are writing the same in mediaqueries it will change margin of all elements which has class margin10 that can cause lot of problems.